# How does c++ evaluate assignment operators (if statement)

Tags: c++, parsing, if-statement, evaluation

Consider the following

```
int main() {
    int a = 8;
    int b = 10;

    while (true) {
        if (a /= 2 && b < 12) {
            b++;
            std::cout << b << std::endl;
        }
        else break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now c++ is not my main language, but how does c++ evaluate this if statement?

In this case, when `b>=12`, the compiler throws the "division by zero" exception, but why?

Now if i wrap the states in parentheses i do not get the exception.

```
if( (a /= 2) && (b < 12))
```

Does this have something to do with how c++ evaluates the statements?

If evaluation is not the problem:

I am aware of that

```
a = (a/2 && b<12)
```

would not hold either.

`P Λ Q` does not hold for `P Λ ¬Q` but the state of P should not be affected? Why is it `P` gets blamed instead of `¬Q`?

Comment: *"I could not try this in java because java does not allow integers to be represented as boolean values in the same way*" - well, just add the ` != 0` and you are good to go. In `C++`, any integer different than `0` evaluates to `true`, so it's not a big problem to simulate this behaviour in `Java`

Comment: @Fureeish well i was not sure on weather java would evaluate it in the same way, therefore i did not want to draw any conclusions trying to force the example on java

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah yes that's true. Assignment of any kind have the next-lowest [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of any operators. You might want to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (a /= 2 && b < 12)
```

is the same as:

```
if (a /= (2 && b < 12))
```

so:

- `2` is evaluated, which is converted to `true` in the context of an operand to `&&`. This does not trigger short-circuit evaluation so we continue...
- `b < 12`, which in the case you're talking about is `false`
- So `2 && b < 12` evaluates to `false` overall
- `a /= 2 && b < 12` is therefore equivalent to `a /= false` here, which is equivalent to `a /= 0`.